# C# Regular Expression - break text into specific pieces

Tags: c#, regex

Friends I am applying R.E `@"^(.*)([0-9/+-^]+)=([0-9]+)$"`on string `"3u->4+5=8"`. While fetching `Group[1]` it returns `"3u->4+"` and `Group[2]` it returns `"5"`.

According to me,

```
Group[0]="3u->4+5=8"   
Group[1]="3u->"   
Group[2]="4+5"   
Group[3]="8"
```

Should be there. Kindly help

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Please provide a reasonable title for your question instead of repeating a bunch of tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the use of a greedy quantifier `.*` than will try to "eat up" everything it can.

Use a lazy quantifier instead:

```
^(.*?)([0-9/+^-]+)=([0-9]+)
```

This will cause `.*?` to match as little a possible while finding an overall match: the quantifier will stop at the `4` in your example.

Also don't forget `-` is a special character inside of a character class, to escape it you need to put it at the beginning or the end (`[...-]`) or `[+-^]` will become a range.

---

**What's happening**

Our regex `(.*)([0-9/+-^]+)`, like any other regex, wants to return a match. In order to do that, it needs to find: "anything with any length, followed by at least a character in the `[0-9/+-^]` range".

Following only this rule, when applied on `3u->4+5` the regex could at first view match:

- `3u->4+` in the first group, `5` in the second (only one digit is *required* for the second group to match)
- `3u->4` in the first group, `+5` in the second
- `3u->` in the first group, `4+5` in the second

So, which one should we match?

In order to know which one to pick, the (heuristic and simplified) rule is:

- if the `*` quantifier is *greedy* it will always try to match the most it can
- if it is *lazy* (so if you're using `*?`) it will match the least it can (while the regex is still returning a global match).

You can read more on the subject [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) or [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), where the general underlying rules and subtleties are being explained more in depth.

Comment: Can u elaborate more?